# Want to make our local build fail if the number of major issues in sonarqube is greater than 50

Tags: java, gradle, sonarqube, build.gradle, gradle.properties

I am new to gradle and sonar qube. I have locally installed the sonarqube but i need to make the gradle build fail locally if the number of major issues are greater than 50.

```
    /*
    build.gradle:

    Please note that this file should not be changed except for local build and deployments.
    Glpdependencies.gradle and build.gradle will be overwritten from glp-core repo. However, they can be modified
    for local testing purposes.
    */

    buildscript {
        ext {
            springBootVersion = '2.0.4.RELEASE'
        }
        repositories {
             mavenLocal()
             maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
             mavenCentral()


             dependencies {
                    classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.2"
            }

         }
        // These are gradle build dependencies and not application requirements
        dependencies {
            classpath 'de.undercouch.download:de.undercouch.download.gradle.plugin:3.4.3'
            classpath "net.linguica.gradle:maven-settings-plugin:0.5"
            classpath "com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-plugin-gradle:3.14.0"
            classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
            classpath "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE"
            //classpath 'io.spring.gradle:dependency-management-plugin:1.0.6.RELEASE'
        }
    }

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'maven'

    apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
    sonarqube {
            properties {
            property "sonar.projectKey", "sum"  
            property "sonar.buildbreaker.skip" , "false"
            }
    }














    group = 'com.test.sonarqube.gradle'



    apply from: 'glpdependencies.gradle'
    apply from: 'version.gradle'

Below is my gradle.properties:

//org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_144.
systemProp.sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
systemProp.sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
systemProp.sonar.forceAuthentication=true
```

If we need to configure somewhere else then please let me know. As this is a gradle project and sonar qube server is also installed in my local system.
I am getting the type of issues etc in sonar qube server but I need to fail the build locally if the number of major issues are greater than 50.
I tried many things but it didnt worked even i added  property 
        property "sonar.buildbreaker.skip" , "false" in build.gradle but its still not working

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0), for SE to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work? ...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/271271)

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to be able to make the Gradle build fail* because it is a synchronous process, and what you're talking about is the application of a [Quality Gate](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/user-guide/quality-gates/), which is an asynchronous process.

It is easy enough to set up a Quality Gate with an Error condition of Major Issues > 50, but Quality Gate status is not calculated until the end of the background task processing.

Once analysis runs locally, an analysis report is bundled and submitted to the server, where is it queued and then processed asynchronously. You can set up a [webhook](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/project-administration/webhooks/) to notify another system when processing is complete. The webhook notification payload includes the Quality Gate stats, but that's not going to help you fail a Gradle build.

OTOH, the procedure for failing a *CI build* is [well-established](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforJenkins-AnalyzinginaJenkinspipeline)

<sup>*without great difficulty</sup>